# Boolean branching statement

Tags: java, boolean

my code will run, but if isBalloon and isRed are both true, it prints "not balloon" instead of "red balloon"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RedBalloon {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    boolean isRed = false;
    boolean isBalloon = false;

    if ((isBalloon == true) && (isRed == false)){
      System.out.println("Balloon");

      if ((isBalloon == true) && (isRed == true)){
        System.out.println("Red balloon");
      }
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Not a balloon");
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's because of the braces. The second `if` statement is inside the first, so after failing the first `if` statement, you jump to the `else`.

Answer (score 1):

The statements are improperly nested. Add braces `{}` and your IDE will format it, revealing the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off, and you missed a closing brace (and `else`). Based on your `print`(s) I think you wanted

```
if (isBalloon) {
    if (isRed) {
        System.out.println("Red balloon");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Balloon");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Not a balloon");
}
```

**or**

```
if (isBalloon && isRed) {
    System.out.println("Red balloon");
} else if (isBalloon) {
    System.out.println("Balloon");
} else {
    System.out.println("Not a balloon");
}
```

Comment: @BrianSnyder Write out the [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) and I think it will become clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've nested your `if`s improperly, as is clear once properly indented.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but I don't know how to fix it.  This is my third week of learning this stuff and I'm kinda lost

Answer (score 0):

In the second if statement you need to add else before the if. This worked for me

Comment: Maybe you could post the code - to illustrate what you mean.